# Is there a way to filter the rows of a table using the contents of a related table in Power BI when the related table uses a Many-to-One relationship?

Tags: sql, database, azure-devops, powerbi, dax

I am pulling data from Azure Devops' automated testing pipeline and I'm working with a set of data generated from those test runs. For every "release" of my project there are some 1,000 or so automated tests that run against the project to ensure it hasn't been broken with my latest commit. The data is stored in a SQL database and I'd like to use Power BI to generate a release table only consisting of successful releases. That is, no failed tests can be in that release.

Here is my table structure.

**releases**

- releaseId[int](Primary Key)
- releaseDate[datetime]
- createdBy[varchar]

**tests**

- releaseId[Int]
- status[varchar] --the value in this column is always either 'passed', 'failed' or 'blacklisted'
- category[varchar]
- testName[varchar]

There is a Many-To-One relationship between my two releaseId columns; for every releaseId in 'releases' there are some 1,000 tests in the 'tests' table which share the same releaseId.

What I've been able to do so far is generate a "FailedTests" table using this expression:

`FailedTests = FILTER(tests, tests[status] = "Failed")`

I would like to be able to generate a copy of my "release" table that filters out any of the releases found in this "FailedTests" table using the releaseId. Something to the effect of:

`SuccessFulReleases = FILTER(releases, releases[releaseId] = FailedTests[releaseId]`

I know that example is impossible since FILTER does not accept another column as an argument to filter a column, but is there any way to get the data I'm looking for with DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and use "IN VALUES" instead of "=" to pass another column as argument in FILTER clause.

**[updates]** After running the dax on the sample data I realized the there was syntax error in previous dax i have given for **SuccessFulReleases** Please use the update one as below :
(You can also follow the screen shots for references pasted below)

```
SuccessFulReleases = FILTER(releases, NOT(releases[releaseId] IN VALUES(FailedTests[releaseId])))
```

```
FailedReleases = FILTER(releases, releases[releaseId] IN VALUES(FailedTests[releaseId])
```

One of the above two examples should give your desired output.

**[updates]** Desired result set is highlighted below for the given data:
[image]

Created a Failed Test table (same as you you are already doing in you initial post):
[image]

Created a Successful releases table using the dax updated above in post:
[image]

There are few blank rows in final table since they were present in "Releases" sheet.

Comment: It doesn't appear that ' is an operator in DAX. Your solution for generating a FailedReleases table seems to work

Comment: Based on my understanding on your explanation of problem. FailedReleases should give your desired result.

Comment: no the visualization I'm hoping to generate is to show a count of how many tests are in my successful releases. So I need a SuccessfulReleases table, not a FailedReleases table

Comment: In this case you can instead of FailedTests table you can create an SucessTest table using below Dax and then use **IN VALUES** function: ``` SuccessTests = FILTER(tests, tests[status] <> "Failed")```

Comment: That doesn't quite work either. Since I have some 1000 tests running, some of them will pass even if one or two fails. What I'm attempting to do is: if one test fails, then the entire release fails regardless if any other test cases succeed. With the "SucceessTests" method, I'll be filtering out all the failed tests but all of the tests that succeeded alongside the failed ones will still be in the list. So the failed releases will still be in my "SucceesfulReleases" table

Comment: Got it, Can you share the link for sample data. It will make it easier for me to test my dax

Comment: Here is a small sample of my dataset. I generated this file from the results of making sql queries against my full db. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0XIR70yjOF352MuHD80BUM_RLnRI32E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Marln, I have requested the access for your dataset file

Comment: Hi Marln, thanks for sharing the data. after running the dax I relalized there was syntax error in first post. I have corrected it. Please review the updated post and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Himanshu Agrawal's method is correct.

I would like to share another method: you could add [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) function in the filter.

```
SuccessFulReleases = FILTER(releases, releases[releaseId] = SELECTEDVALUE (FailedTests[releaseId]))
```

In this case, you could use `=`.